# Why do we fuse Odom, IMU, GPS and other pose messages?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with navigation stack lately, and I have a indoor location system to get the absolute pose of the robot.

As we all know, the odometry is only right for a short time, so I want to correct the pose with my indoor location system.

I know there is a package *robot_pose_ekf* can fuse /odom, /imu_data and /vo. But my question is Why do we have to fuse these pose messages? Why don't we just make the /odom correct with indoor location system or GPS or something else?

---

### EDIT

Hi mig,

Actually, I tried to adapt the tf `map->odom` before. But I found it hard to deal with the orientaion. You know, to adapt the position (x,y,z), you just need to do some additions and subtractions, however, when it comes to the orientation, if you change it (Quaternion: x, y, z, w), the position of `base_link` relative to `map` will change as well. And I also tried to do some 'cos' and 'sin' calculation, but I didn't get the right tf result.

So, is there any packages I can use or refer for this tf `map->odom`? I know `amcl` did such thing, but its source code is hard to understand.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241922/why-do-we-fuse-odom,-imu,-gps-and-other-pose-messages?/) by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 763 on 2016-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The difference between those is how/what they measure.

Odometry, IMU and Visual Odometry (I guess this what you mean with `vo`) just measure the internal state of the robot, and thus just deliver relative measurements towards a starting pose and cannot correct for long-term drifts. However, you can fuse those using the `robot_pose_ekf` to achieve a more stable "fused" odometry guess.

Then, you need a localization that is providing measurements with respect to "world". This can be GPS, IPS, cameras with stored, localized features or laserscanners with a given map. With those, you can correct the drift of the "fused" odometry.

There are several packages providing this or parts of this functionality, e.g. `robot_localization` or `amcl`, to name just two.

---

EDIT

You are right, I did not think of adding a GPS sensor like this. Seems like I misunderstood how they define visual odometry here. However, a world fixed frame does not mean that this is fixed over multiple runs. Typically, any odometry starts of from the pose of the robot where it is turned on. In contrast there are fixed frames  (like map coordinates) that are the same whether you turn this on or not.

Thus, `vo` provides measurements to the `vo` frame which can different any time you launch the robot, depending on what you use for input.

---

EDIT 2

Typically, when you add a sensor providing "global corrections", you don't correct the `odom` frame. The tf `odom->base_link` is what is typically provided by internal sensors, i.e. wheel encoders, IMU and visual odometry.

If you have another sensor (GPS, laserscanner, ...) I would prefer to adapt the tf `map->odom` such that the tree  `map->odom->base_link` is correct. This is how it is typically done for mobile robots in ROS, thus I'd prefer this solution.

---

EDIT 3

[This is where the magic happens](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/amcl/src/amcl_node.cpp#L1350-L1380) in amcl.

You can use the `TransformPose` function of [TF](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Overview/Using%20Published%20Transforms#transformDATA_Methods) to get `map->odom` (called `odom_to_map` therein)  from the `map->base_link` that you estimate, and broadcast this (after you bring it into the correct format...)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shay](https://answers.ros.org/users/27777/shay/) on 2016-08-18**:
Thanks for your answer. But I'm still confused.
I thought the *robot_pose_ekf* not just fuses relative measurements, because it now supports GPS too. And I thought /vo is also the global pose relative to "world"